# QT:Crashing Issue Due to The Order of Object Creation

Tags: c++, qt

Description:
I am developing a Qt application that includes a main window (Window1) along with a client (Client) and server (Server) objects. I have implemented custom close signals to handle the closing behavior, and I dynamically create and show these objects in the MStimulatorShow function of the Window1 class.

I have noticed that when I create and connect the server object first based on a condition, and then create and connect the client object, the closing operation works fine(no matter which window is the first to close). However, when I change the order of creation and connection(i mean the "if" in the code snippet), creating and connecting the client object first and then the server object, the closing operation of server causes the whole application to crash.
i noticed the slot:"onServerClosed" can be triggered,and it is there where the application crashs.
im not sure either it is caused by the order of object creation or the order of the connect,and server has no relationship with client;
Here is a relevant code:

```
void Window1::MStimulatorShow() {
    if (!server) {
        server = new Server(this);
        connect(server, &Server::closed, this, &Window1::onServerClosed);
    }
    if (!client) {
        client = new Client(this);
        connect(client, &Client::closed, this, &Window1::onClientClosed);
    }
    client->show();
    server->show();
    qDebug() << "MStimulatorShow invoked";
}

void Window1::onClientClosed() {
    disconnect(client, &Client::closed, this, &Window1::onClientClosed);
    client->deleteLater();
    client = nullptr;
    qDebug() << "onClientClosed invoked";
}

void Window1::onServerClosed() {
    disconnect(server, &Server::closed, this, &Window1::onServerClosed);
    server->deleteLater();
    server = nullptr;
    qDebug() << "onServerClosed invoked";
}
//cons and destructor of Server
Server::Server(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Server)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    localip=new QString(getLocalIP());
    setWindowTitle("local IP:"+*localip);
    tcpserver= new QTcpServer(this);
    ui->act_stop->setEnabled(false);
    ui->send_btn->setEnabled(false);
    ui->btn_terminate->setEnabled(false);
}
Server::~Server()
{
    if(ui)delete ui;
    if(statusbar)delete statusbar;
    if(lbl_listening)delete lbl_listening;
    if(lbl_socketstate)delete lbl_socketstate;
    if(tcpsocket)delete tcpsocket;
    if(tcpserver)delete tcpserver;
    if(localip)delete localip;
}
//cons and destructor of Server

Client::Client(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Client)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    tcpclient=new QTcpSocket(this);
    LocalIP=new QString;
    *LocalIP=std::move(getLocalIP());
    setWindowTitle("Tcp Client"+*LocalIP);
    //connect(ui->bnt_toConnectServer,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&Client::ConnectServer)
    connect(tcpclient,&QTcpSocket::connected,this,&Client::onConnected);
    connect(tcpclient,&QTcpSocket::disconnected,this,&Client::onDisconnected);
    connect(tcpclient,&QTcpSocket::readyRead,this,&Client::onSocketReadyRead);
    connect(tcpclient, &QTcpSocket::stateChanged, this, &Client::onSocketStateChange);
}
Client::~Client()
{
    if(ui)delete ui;
    if(LocalIP)delete LocalIP;
    if(tcpclient)delete tcpclient;
}
//slots
void Client::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    emit closed();
    qDebug() << "Client::closeEvent invoked";
}

void Server::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    emit closed();
    qDebug() << "Server::closeEvent invoked";
}
```

Comment: First you need to identify where it crashes. You have not specified this. There is also not enough code shown to rule out basic errors such as uninitialized values. It would pay to implement a destructor in `Server` and `Client` classes, and set a breakpoint to check that a double-deletion is not happening. Qt does support a mechanism that will automatically delete on close. As for explicitly disconnecting a slot from a signal while handling that signal, I dunno if that's a normal thing to do. Seems sketchy to me. If you remove the explicit `disconnect`, does the crash go away?

Comment: @paddy, i added codes and specified where exactly it crashes , thank for your tip

Answer (score 0):

I know what's wrong with it. in my destructor there'are some line like `if(tcpsocket)delete tcpsocket;`,but the pointer `tcpsocket` is not initialized until the slots`onNewConnection` is triggered.and I just open the window and close it right away, the initializing is not done.so the application crashes.
but changing the order of the creations of server and client will make the application works fine, this is still confusing.